# Python (Flask + Swagger) Flasgger throwing 404 error

Tags: python, flask, swagger, flasgger

I am trying to use swagger ui as a frontend to query my flask application. I'm using [Flasgger](https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger) I tried a toy example as shown below

```
from flasgger import Swagger
from flask import Flask, logging

app = Flask(__name__)
Swagger(app)


# ENDPOINT = 1
@app.route('/hello',methods=['GET'])
def helloapp():
    return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,threaded=True,port=7005)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('app.log')
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

When i try to query the endpoint `http://localhost:7005/hello`. I get the result with 'Hello World'.

If I try to query `http://localhost:7005/apidocs/` This shows me the base UI [image]

---

But, when I try to query the endpoint root. The swagger UI does not show up. It throws me a 404 Error

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Any pointers as to what is the issue ?.

Comment: try without `http://`

Comment: @Roman, It did not work

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the endpoint root to your routes like this:

```
@app.route('/')

@app.route('/hello',methods=['GET'])
# ...
```

Because you didn't define it as a route, it cannot be found on the server.
I hope that this will help you